# React App Nginx config static file alias not working

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Some strange happens - never get it before.
Simple config for React App:

```
  root "/home/imok_www";
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =401;
    gzip_static on;
  }
  location /images/ {
    alias "/home/store/images/";
    autoindex off;
  }
```

But got 404 error:

```
2020/04/12 01:32:55 [error] 16587#0: *1 open() "/home/imok_www/images/21ab8d00-4e48-481e-8034-4195b8c4829f_200.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.8.135.86, server: imok.fit, request: "GET /images/21ab8d00-4e48-481e-8034-4195b8c4829f_200.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "imok.fit"
```

Nginx try to looking for files in root directory, ignore alias config... Nginx user has allow to read from store directory.

```
bash-4.2# su nginx
bash-4.2$ ls /home/store/images/21ab8d00-4e48-481e-8034-4195b8c4829f_200.jpg 
/home/store/images/21ab8d00-4e48-481e-8034-4195b8c4829f_200.jpg
```

Comment: Is that the entire `server` block?

Comment: No, inside virtual host config

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire `server` block. Alternatively, read [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution:

1. Change locations from

```
  location /images/ {
```

to

```
  location ^~ /images/ {
```

will change error from 404 to 403. After that:

2. Add Selinux access:

```
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /home/store/images/
```